# Survminer - ggforest, how to change variable names?

Tags: r, survival-analysis, r-forestplot

Hello to everybody and thank you for your help. I'm managing to build a forest plot of a Cox model with the Survminer package, however, I've got stuck in trying to change the labels of the variables displayed. Is there a way to change the labels displayed without changing variable names? How could I update my string in order to change the names?

```
ggforest<-ggforest(coxph, data=data)
```

[image: This image is obtained]

If I try to use the legend.labs function I obtain this error

```
ggforest(coxph, data=data, legend.title = c("Prova"),legend.labs=c("Carried AED","Daytime", "Distance 1","Distance 2", "Distance 3"))
Error in ggforest(coxph, data = data, legend.title = c("Prova"), legend.labs = c("Carried AED",  : 
  unused arguments (legend.title = c("Prova"), legend.labs = c("Carried AED", "Daytime", "Distance 1", "Distance 2", "Distance 3"))
```

Can you help me with changing these labels?

Thank you again

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a workaround based on @Quintens answer:

```r
library(forestmodel)
library(survival)

labelled::var_label(colon) <- list(
    sex = "Sex", #this variable is a numeric -> label works
    rx = "RX", # factor -> label doesn't work!
    adhere = "ADHERE" # numeric -> label works...
)

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere, data = colon)

print(forest_model(model))
```

[image]

```r
# this does the trick
model$xlevels <- unname(model$xlevels)

print(forest_model(model))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Based on this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/kassambara/survminer/issues/405) it seems not possible to change the printed variables' names in a `ggforest` without changing the variable names. They suggest to use the `labelled` package to label the variable names with the `forestmodel`. One problem here is that changing the names only works for numerical variables. I don't have your data, so I will give a reproducible example using the `colon` dataset:

```r
library(forestmodel)
library(survival)
labelled::var_label(colon) <- list(
  sex = "Sex", #this variable is a numeric -> label works
  rx = "RX", # factor -> label doesn't work!
  adhere = "ADHERE" # numeric -> label works...
)

model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex + rx + adhere, data = colon)

print(forest_model(model)) 
#> Warning in recalculate_width_panels(panel_positions, mapped_text =
#> mapped_text, : Unable to resize forest panel to be smaller than its heading;
#> consider a smaller text size
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Check this [conversation](https://github.com/NikNakk/forestmodel/issues/24#issuecomment-825150537) for extra info.

Comment: I wonder if giving the factor entry a list with level names might succeed? It would be more in the classical R style.